# Do you ever pronounce "thought" the same as "taught"?

Tags: pronunciation

I'm doing a course on Edx. In that episode the lecturer pronounces "thought" almost the same as "taught". The time point is 8:15, multiplication rule lecture 1.3, Stat_2.2x. 8:20 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipwZ-8LsG3E&list=PL2fCZiDqOYYWHVVeHGTnIK_C3pB3W-o-M&index=4) on YouTube.

I've searched the pronunciation difference between these two words, in a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVNhOAEW784) on Youtube, the teacher doesn't mention this case.

So, do you sometimes pronounce "thought" the same as "taught"? Is it allowed to ignore "h" sometimes informally?

Comment: Sylvester certainly does! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MvNfPSXWZqw

Comment: The only one I ever heard say "thought" that way was WB Tweety-bird, watch here on YouTube [**Looney Tunes Super Stars Tweety and Sylvester**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYhNljS5Sug) at 1:04. If I heard someone say this I would think it childish at best.

Comment: Wow.  I completely mis-typed.  I meant Tweety Bird *about* Sylvester. Ooops.

Comment: Maybe in an old movie that parodied Italian-Americans' pronunciation.  "I tot you was gonna take care a dat ting."

Comment: In some dialects of English, the dental fricative (your "th")  is pronounced "t".   Some Irish people say it that way, for example.

Comment: And some speakers of Indian English, who speak other native languages in which one of the [d] sounds is "retroflex", i.e. produced with the tip of the tongue quite far back on the roof of the mouth rather than directly behind the front teeth on the hard ridge there, will produce a fairly plosive fricative when speaking English words with "th".  Listen: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_retroflex_stop

Comment: For what it's worth, pronouncing /θ/ and /ð/ as [t] and [d] is actually a feature of English varieties around the globe, including various dialects in both the US and UK: https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=mtd3a-56ysUC&ots=H_CHXs1wwU&pg=PA1123#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only are the two pronounced differently, but confusing the two is (in American English) grounds for humor. The classic example is the phrase "I taught I taw a puddy-tat", used by the cartoon character Tweety-Bird. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38aDWDUjlOY for the original cartoon.

Answer (score 2):

No we don't say *thought* as *taught*. (Except *maybe* by certain Irish speakers of English, who say *thanks* as *tanks*.)

The person in this video says *thought*. She doesn't pronounce it almost the same as *taught*. One cannot even do that. There is either the *th* or not. This person also says *thought* at 7:51. She may have a slightly unique pronunciation, but she's saying *thought*.

Saying it as *taught* is not an option, except for the one possible exception I know of, or other similar dialect. But not in any major dialect.